# Error message comes up even if input is correct. python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am trying to allow certain input  with this code.

```
Sdepth = int(input("enter depth of slab: "))
if Sdepth != 45 or Sdepth != 38 :
    print("depth can only be 45 or 38")
    Sdepth = int(input("enter depth of slab: "))
```

If I input 45 or 38 `print("depth can only be 45 or 38")` is output when it should not.

Comment: If Sdepth is 45, it is still not 38. You mean `and`, not `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `and`, not `or` in this case. For example, if you enter `45`, `Sdepth != 38` is still `True`, thus the whole if condition is `True`. Or you can use `if Sdepth not in (45, 38):`

Answer (score 1):

`Sdepth != 45 or Sdepth != 38` evaluates to `True` if either or `Sdepth != 45` or `Sdepth != 38` is `True`.  If `Sdepth` is 38, then `Sdepth != 45` is `True`.

Change the `if` line to this:

```
if Sdepth not in [38, 45]:
```